# Is there any way to encrypt form data header values which can be seen in network resources?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, encryption, ssh, erlang

[image: Facebook's form data]*I am able to see my credentials in network of the browser*

I don't know if that is supposed to be like that or a problem of browser

But for my website, I don't want this in ruby on rails or java.

Comment: The above picture contains facebook's form data

Comment: This question over on Information Security addresses this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54656/protecting-form-post-values-when-on-https

Comment: It's supposed to be like that. It's not a problem. *"But for my website, I don't want this in ruby on rails or java."*  I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Https does encrypt the whole request including the headers. The reason you are seeing them, I believe, is because you are using the capabilities of the very same browser in which it was generated. Try to spoof the packages outside the browser, which by virtue of being the originator of the information can have a pick at it.